# Using the AWS S3 Java SDK, what is the fastest way to determine if the authorization (access key and secret key) is correct?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need a quick way to determine if the authorization (access key and secret key) is correct for AWS S3.

I have found a slow solution: Calling AmazonS3Client.getS3AccountOwner will result in signing a request and sending it to AWS, and getting a failure if your access key / secret key aren't correct.  Unfortunately, this takes 200-300 ms.

I've found a way to accomplish this in Azure in 60 ms using the code below:

```
            final CloudBlobContainer container =
                    m_client.getContainerReference( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
            container.exists();
```

The equivalent of the above for S3 doesn't work for my purpose (or at least I've not been able to figure out how to use it for my purpose).  Anybody have any ideas as to how I can cut down on the time to determine if the authorization is correct from 200-300 ms with the approach I found?

Answer (score 1):

A check like that does not provide any value in AWS. An access key and a secret key may match but there may not be any IAM policies or the policies may be limited for the IAM user. So just because the keys are valid doesn't mean you'll be able to list buckets or download a file with those credentials.

You should check the result of the S3 operation to determine if the permissions were insufficient for the operation and act accordingly at that time.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this code goes in a place where I just need to verify that the access key and secret key are valid.  I don't need to verify access to any buckets or anything at this point.  Thus, my question still stands :)  How can I quickly determine if an access key / secret key combination is valid?

Comment: Your question may still be standing, but it's having trouble doing that, because there is no obvious point to such a test.  Credentials can be correct and valid but still be entirely unusable.  The error on failure of a real request will give you a much better idea of the nature of the problem, if that occurs.